# Dificuldade com Context API [REACT]

Tags: javascript, react, contexto

preciso que um componente timer seja refletido em outro componente distante. Para tal, criei um contexto para guardar os estados dos timers criados, visto que o timer posterior (depende de ação do usuário) deve iniciar de forma sincronizada com o timer de origem.

Já tentei usar diversas abordagens porém o timer derivado sempre começa no estado padrão de 5 minutos. É como se cada vez que eu criasse um componente de timer o React recriasse a instância do contexto/ estado e isso não faz o menor sentido.

Resumindo, o contexto é responsável por iterar cada timer adicionado e setar as alterações. O componente timer é refletido usando o parentId.

Segue o código:

**TIMER**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import { TimersContext, useTimers } from './context/timer';

import AccessAlarmIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccessAlarm';

import styles from './styles';
import clsx from 'clsx';


const Timer = ({ parentId, updater, card }) => {
    
    const classes = makeStyles(styles)();
    const { handleNewTimer, timers } = useTimers();
    const timer = timers.find(t => t.parentId === parentId);

    useEffect(() => {
        handleNewTimer(parentId, updater);
    });

    return (
        <div className={clsx(classes.container, card && classes.cardStyle)}>
            {
                card && <span style={{ marginBottom: '3px' }}>
                    Atualiza em
                </span> 
            }
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <AccessAlarmIcon style={{ marginRight: '3px' }} />
                0{timer?.minutes}:{timer?.seconds < 10 ?  `0${timer?.seconds}` : timer?.seconds}s    
            </div>
        </div>
    )
    
}

export default Timer;
```

**CONTEXTO**

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';

export const TimersContext = createContext();

export default function TimersProvider({ children }) {
        
    const [timers, setTimers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        let myInterval = setTimeout(() => {
            for (var i=0; i < timers.length; i++) {
                let timer = timers[i];
                if (timer.seconds === 0) {
                    if (timer.minutes === 0) {
                        timer.updater();
                        return;
                    }
                    timer.selfUpdate(timer); 
                    setTimers([...timers]); 
                } else {
                    timer.setSeconds(timer);
                    setTimers([...timers]); 
                }
            }
        }, 1000)

        return () => clearTimeout(myInterval);      
    }, [timers])

    const handleNewTimer = (parentId, updater) => {
        let timerExists = timers.find(t => t.parentId === parentId);
        if (!timerExists) {
            const newTimer = Object.create({
                minutes: 5,
                seconds: 0,
                setSeconds: (timer) => {
                    timer.seconds = timer.seconds -1; // use this                   
                },
                selfUpdate: (timer) => {
                    timer.seconds = 59;
                    timer.minutes = timer.minutes -1; // use this                    
                },
                updater,
                parentId
            })
            setTimers([...timers.filter(t => t.parentId !== newTimer.parentId), newTimer]); 
        } else {
            console.log('Timer is already running.', timers);
        }
    }

    
    return (
        <TimersContext.Provider value={{ timers, handleNewTimer }}>
            {children}
        </TimersContext.Provider>
    )
}

export function useTimers() {
    const context = useContext(TimersContext);

    return context;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando o mesmo contexto e parentId, essa implementação deveria funcionar.

Para usar o mesmo contexto deve ter apenas um TimersProvider em volta de todos os Timers. Tendo o mesmo contexto, todas as vezes que adicionar um novo Timer com o mesmo parentId de algum anterior ele vai começar a contagem com o mesmo tempo do anterior. Todas as vezes que adicionar um Timer com parentId diferente dos outros, ele vai começar em 5 minutos.

Eu montei um componente usando os componentes que você criou:

```
export default (props) => {
  const [parentIds, setParentIds] = React.useState(["first"]);

  return (
    <TimersProvider>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-around" }}>
        {parentIds.map((parentId, idx) => (
          <Timer
            key={`${parentId}-${idx}`}
            parentId={parentId}
            updater={console.log}
          />
        ))}
      </div>

      <button
        onClick={() => setParentIds([...parentIds, random(0, 3000).toString()])}
      >
        Adicionar random
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setParentIds([...parentIds, parentIds[0]])}>
        Adicionar Cópia do primeiro
      </button>
    </TimersProvider>
  );
};
```

Sempre que clico no primeiro botão, adicionar um timer com parentId aleatório, ele adiciona um timer que começa em 5 minutos.

Sempre que clico no segundo botão, adicionar cópia do primeiro, ele adiciona um novo timer com o mesmo parentId do primeiro, iniciando, assim, no mesmo tempo que o primeiro estiver.

Única alteração que eu indico que seja feita é a adição do segundo Parametro do useEffect dentro do timer porque você só quer que ele registre esse Timer assim que ele é renderizado pela primeira vez não toda vez que ele é renderizado.

```
useEffect(() => {
    handleNewTimer(parentId, updater);
  }, []);
```

[Sandbox utilizando seu código e esse componente da resposta](https://codesandbox.io/s/dificuldades-context-api-xxem4?file=/src/Timer.js:336-350)